# Change background-image with attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

I have this link:

```
<div class="wp-show-posts-inner" data-src="http://maria138.coroleu.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/foto1.jpg"></div>
```

I need to change `background-image` url from another class with `data-url` on hover event.
I try this right now but doesn't work:

```
var bg_img = jQuery('.wp-show-posts-inner').attr('data-src');    
jQuery('.wp-show-posts-inner').on('mouseover',function() {    
  jQuery('.home-banner .bg').css({'background-image': "url('"+bg_img+"')"});
});
```

This script get me this result:

```
element.style {
  background-image: url((unknown));
}
```

i need this:

```
<div class="bg" style="background-image: url(http://maria138.coroleu.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/foto1.jpg);"></div>
```

any advice? thanks

Comment: You should use `$(this).attr('data-src')` instead. Also remove `'` at end of `.css()`

Comment: *Always* check the console. With that code it'll be singing errors at you.

Comment: This may not meet your requirements, but if the idea is simply to change a background image on hover, then it could be done nicely in pure CSS rather than JS with a `:hover` selector.

Comment: @DBS i cannot use :hover because my attribute url i get it from PHP. I put url directly because is more simple to explain. Thanks

Comment: @Mohammad, i delete ' but console show me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . Thanks

Comment: @Utkanos thanks, i will start to look check.

Comment: @user1706064 Did you checked my answer? i wrote problem of your code in it

Comment: I update mi publication. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong for getting attr data-src, use this

```js
var bg_img = jQuery('.wp-show-posts-inner').attr('data-src');
jQuery('.wp-show-posts-inner').on('mouseover',function() {    
      jQuery('.home-banner .bg').css({'background-image': "url('"+bg_img+"')"});
});
jQuery('.wp-show-posts-inner').on('mouseleave',function() {    
      jQuery('.home-banner .bg').css({'background-image': "url()"});
});
```

```css
.bg{height:100px;width:100px;}
.wp-show-posts-inner{height:100px;width:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home-banner">
<div class="bg">

</div>
</div>
<div class="wp-show-posts-inner" data-src="http://maria138.coroleu.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/foto1.jpg">wp-show-posts-inner (Hover on me)</div>
```

Comment: Console show me this error: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function. Thanks

Comment: edited the answer, i hope you have included jQuery library

Comment: Well, the code doesnt show me any error, but doesnt do anything. This is my web: http://maria138.coroleu.com/ and i need to do the same of this web: http://www.peterlindbergh.com/

Comment: Edited again. Please have a look

Comment: Doesnt work, your code create this rule:
element.style {
    background-image: url((unknown));
}

Comment: Solved:
    jQuery('.wp-show-posts-inner').on('mouseover',function() {  
      var bg_img = jQuery(this).attr('data-src');  
      jQuery('.home-banner .bg').css('background-image', 'url(' + bg_img + ')');
    });

Answer (score 0):

You code has three problem.

1. You should use selector before using `.attr()`. So use `$(this).attr('data-src')`
2. In end of second parameter of `.css()` there is additional `'` that should removed
3. css `background-image` property should wrapped into `url()`

So you code should change to

```
$('.wp-show-posts-inner').hover(function() {    
    $('.home-banner .bg').css('background-image', "url("+$(this).attr('data-src')+")");
});
```

```js
$('.wp-show-posts-inner').hover(function() {    
  $('.home-banner .bg').css('background-image', "url("+$(this).attr('data-src')+")");
});
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wp-show-posts-inner" data-src="http://maria138.coroleu.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/foto1.jpg">wp-show-posts-inner</div>
<div class="home-banner">
  <div class="bg">bg</div>
</div>
```